# DirectorySearcher not working for Windows 7 64 bit or 32 bit over network

Tags: .net, directoryservices

I have an application that resides on a network drive.

When the program runs from an XP machine on the desktop or over the network the program works for any user.  When it runs from Win 7 on the desktop it works for everyone, but when it runs from Win 7 over the network it fails for users with fewer permissions.  Below is the code.  It fails on the last line "Dim searchResult As SearchResult = directorySearcher.FindOne"

```
Dim adpath As String = "LDAP://OU=orgOU,DC=ad,DC=orgDC,DC=edu"
Dim directoryEntry As New DirectoryEntry(adpath)
directoryEntry.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure
Dim directorySearcher As New DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry)
directorySearcher.Filter = getFilter(samAccountName)
directorySearcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree
Dim searchResult As SearchResult = directorySearcher.FindOne
```

Can anyone tell me what is missing in the network permissions?

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be using serverless binding, try setting:

```
AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure | AuthenticationTypes.ReadonlyServer
```

From the MSDN documentation on `AuthenticationTypes.ReadOnlyServer`:

> For Active Directory Domain Services, this flag indicates that a writable server is not required for a serverless binding.

Also you should be disposing your disposable objects, preferably with the Using statement.  Something like:

```
Using directoryEntry = New DirectoryEntry...

Using directorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(...
```