# How to use SSL for System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory?

Tags: c#, .net

I managed to set up an windows 2003 Active Directory for SSL, both StartTLS and LDAPS, this I have verified using the Ldp.exe from Windows Resource Toolkit. I am also able to query the contents of the directory using LdapConnection object in C# .NET.

I would like to proceed to use SSL for my Active Directory queries, for example:

[Domain.GetDomain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.domain.getdomain.aspx)

I have tried using

```
domain = Domain.GetDomain(new DirectoryContext(DirectoryContextType.DirectoryServer, mydomain + ":636", username, password));
```

But it seems to not be talking LDAPS to the port 636, I get the following Exception

```
System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.ActiveDirectoryObjectNotFoundException: Domain controller "ad.rambutan.com:636" does not exist or cannot be contacted.
```

The same goes for Forest.GetForest.

Is there a way to get Domain.GetDomain to work over SSL? Either StartTLS or LDAPS would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

The docs for [DirectoryContextType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.directorycontext.aspx) do not mention LDAPS, so I don't think that you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

You doe not appear to be able to do it using Domain.GetDomain but you can do it using the [DirectoryEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.aspx) class by setting the [AuthenticationType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.authenticationtype.aspx) property to [SecureSocketsLayer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.authenticationtypes.aspx). See [DirectorySearcher not working for Windows 7 64 bit or 32 bit over network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339977/directorysearcher-not-working-for-windows-7-64-bit-or-32-bit-over-network) for an example.